# Linux Perf equivalent for: dtrace -n 'io:::start /execname == "kworker"/ { printf("%d %s %s", pid, execname, fileinfo_t}'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I need to do something like:

```
dtrace -n 'io:::start /execname == "kworker"/ { printf("%d %s %s", pid, execname, fileinfo_t}'
```

using perf.. how do i do so? Where's the perf language documented? The problem i'm facing is this: I have some app generating *WRITE to sdc* - i know the app is *kworker* but I need to figure out why kworker is doing this (i'm using a flash disk so i'm write sensitive)?

I'm seeing lines like this in *dmesg*:

```
[17621.884263] kworker/u4:2(18327): WRITE block 794104 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
```

Comment: perf is a frigging pain! Dtrace is so much more nicer and well designed.. perf's like a mush of something weird.

Comment: Note: the *dtrace* example may/may-not work - but it's easy to express what needs to be done - C syntax.

Comment: i'm using systemtap for this - i doubt it can be done using perf